# VB.NET Loop Collection And Get Value

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS to loop through some attachments, however if I come across an email that has multiple attachments I only want to download a particular attachment.

To do this I figured I could just test to see if the AttachmentCollection Contains the particular attachment name and only download that attachment.

How can I loop through AttachmentCollection and test each name of the Attachment?

I can't do an AttachmentCollection.Contains because it contains a Collection of Attachments and not the name of the attachments themselves.

Comment: You can use the `.Count` property and loop over the items in it like an array, e.g., `myCollection[i]` [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachmentcollection?view=exchange-ews-api). It also has an iterator, so you should also be able to do a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with the types involved by I believe that that `AttachmentCollection` implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`, which means you can use some LINQ on it. You can test for and get the attachment using something like this:

```vb
Dim attachment = myAttachmentCollection.FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.Name = someValue)

If attachment IsNot Nothing Then
    'A match was found and attachment refers to it.
End If
```

Not sure what the item type is so you may not have a `Name` property but the principle is the same.

EDIT:

For the record, the equivalent of `Contains` would be `Any`:

```vb
If myAttachmentCollection.Any(Function(a) a.Name = someValue) Then
```

That's fine if all you want to know is whether a match exists but, if you want to get the matching item too, you wouldn't use `Any` first because then you'd be enumerating twice. `FirstOrDefault` does pretty much the same as `Any` except it returns the matching item if one is found or `Nothing` if no matches are found rather than returning `True` if a match is found or `False` if no matches are found.